# Looking for a specific attribute containing a specific word

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am tasked with going through our entire site, each `aspx` and `ascx` page and code behind `.cs` files to replace a word with another. the `ctrl-shift-f`, find all, functionality with regex came to mind, however, my regex pattern I made seems to find attribute names which doesn't necessarily contain the word I want to replace.

In my case, I am trying to replace the words "Supply site, Suppliers, Supply or Supplier" with "depot". Some things to note - we can ignore CDATA[], attributes always have a quotation mark `"` instead of an apostrophe. Additionally, for now I am only trying to cover our design layer- aspx and ascx files, so we are dealing with HTML. We don't have any HTML text, (e.g `<label> HELLO </label>`)

Regex

```
((Text|HeaderText|ToolTip).*|\n*(Supply|Supplysite|Supply\Ssite|Supplier))$
```

The Question:
How can I change my regex to strictly find `Text`, `HeaderText` or `ToolTip` attributes which contains `Supply/Supplysite/Supply site/ Supplier/ Suppliers` ?

Comment: If you're talking about _attributes_ (a code example would be useful) shouldn't there be an `=` character to indicate/denote the start of the content for the attribute? If yes, use it in your regex.

Comment: Sounds like `\s(Text|HeaderText|ToolTip)="[^"]*(Supply(?:\s?site)?|Supplier)[^"]*"`

Comment: yeah, I tried to skip through it by a greedy match all (as to ignore the =" after the keywords "Text/ToolTip/HeaderText")

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew bravo. that's the ticket - does exactly what I need. Post it as your answer please , I will tick it as soon as I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\s(Text|HeaderText|ToolTip)="[^"]*(Supply(?:\s?site)?|Supplier)[^"]*"
```

**Details**

- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(Text|HeaderText|ToolTip)` - any of the three alternative substrings
- `="` - a `="` substring
- `[^"]*` - any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `(Supply(?:\s?site)?|Supplier)` - either of the two:

  - `Supply(?:\s?site)?` - `Supply` optionally followed with an optional whitespace and `site` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `Supplier` - a `Supplier` substring
- `[^"]*` - any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HMbcOM/1).